# QML: How to implement signal handler of a child

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

I'm editing a component in Qt Creator. It suggested me to split the component in UI and not UI parts. My components exposes 2 custom properties.

```
ComponentViewForm {
    property string step: '0'
    property string setStep: '0'
}
```

1. A TextInput inside the UI-Part is bound to `step`
2. It should set the property `setStep` in `onAccepted` handler.

First one is easy. The binding can be edited in UI-Editor directly
But how do I implement the signal-handler of the child?
I've implemented it directly in the UI.

```
TextInput {
    id: step
    text: parent.step
    onAccepted:
    {
        parent.setStep = text
    }
}
```

It works, but Qt-Creator rejects to open it in UI-mode any more.

Comment: Little advice from guys who is writing on QML almost 6 years - forget about UI mode, it's like UI mode for HTML. Of course you can get some work done with it, but one step left or one step right from straight line (let me know if you don't understand my idiom) makes you stuck.

Comment: Great, valuable advice, thanks! Good comparison with HTML. If it really like this, I'll go for text mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [export](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-quick-ui-forms.html#using-qt-quick-ui-forms) the `TextInput` from your `ComponentViewForm`. There's a small *Export* button in the *Navigator* tab in Qt Quick UI forms editor. Assume that the id of `TextInput` is `stepInput`, ComponentViewForm.ui.qml should have an alias property `property alias stepInput: stepInput` in source code after you click the *Export* button.
[image: Export]

You can implement property binding and signal handlers in ComponentView.qml like this:

```
ComponentViewForm {
    property string step: '0'
    property string setStep: '0'

    stepInput.text: step
    stepInput.onAccepted:
    {
        setStep = stepInput.text;
    }
}
```